# Upload Files in php using REST

Tags: php, rest, file-upload, curl

Is there a way to upload a file from a client side to the server using REST using PHP,

I am trying to use the below code, and it is not working from me.

```
<?php

$file_to_upload = array('file_contents'=>'@c:\\test.txt');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/api/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file_to_upload);
 curl_exec($ch) or die( curl_error($ch) );
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo " Server response: ".$result;
echo " Curl Error: ".$error;

?>
```

and my upload.php

```
$uploaddir = realpath('./') . '/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_POST['file']['name']);

echo $uploadfile;
echo "\n";
echo '<pre>';
echo $_POST['file']['tmp_name'];
       if (move_uploaded_file($_POST['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
           echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
       } else {
           echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
       }
       echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';

      print_r($_FILES);
       echo "\n<hr />\n";
       print_r($_POST);
print "</pr" . "e>\n";
?>
```

Comment: I think you should be looking for `$_FILES['file_contents']` and not `$_POST['file']`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I think you should be looking for `$_FILES['file_contents']` and not
>   `$_POST['file']`. – user1190992

Answer (score 8):

Try this.

index.php

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_FILES);
    error_reporting(9);
    if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'submit') {
        $ch = curl_init();
        $filePath = $_FILES['file_upl']['tmp_name'];
        $fileName = $_FILES['file_upl']['name'];
        $data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => "@$filePath", 'fileName' =>$fileName);             
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.restServiceHost.com/file3/upload.php');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
?>

<form name="file_up" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Upload your file here
<input type="file" name="file_upl" id="file_upl"/>
<input type="submit" name="action" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

and upload.php in http://www.restServiceHost.com/file3

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    echo 'in upload.php<br/>';
    print_r($_FILES);
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_REQUEST["fileName"]);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

php5.5+

```
$filePath = $_FILES['file_upl']['tmp_name'];
$type=$_FILES['file_upl']['type'];
$fileName = $_FILES['file_upl']['name'];
    
$data = array('file_upl' => curl_file_create($filePath, $type, $fileName));

$ch = curl_init();     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/api/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```